# How to disable cut-copy-paste pop up in webview on text selection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

How do I disable the cut-copy-paste pop-up in a web view in Flutter? I want the text selection feature to remain as it is, but I don't want the pop-up to appear. I googled a lot but nothing worked for me.

I am using [this Flutter WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter).

[image: cut copy paste popup screenshot]